# GIT log command to extract pull request titles

Tags: git, git-log, git-shell

I have a huge repository which has multiple folders inside it. Each of these folders is a separate application. Below is a sample of the repo structure:

```
myGitRepo/
 A/
 B/
 C/
 .git
```

I have been trying to use git log to fetch Pull request titles. However I want to filter it for a specific folder i.e "C".

Post using below command I was able to extract Pull request titles based on time:

```
git --git-dir=.git log --merges --since="Wed Oct 10 07:57:32 UTC 2018"
```

However when I try to filter these PR titles based on my folder, it doesnt work. I have used below command:

```
git --git-dir=.git log --merges --since="Wed Oct 10 07:57:32 UTC 2018" -- myGitRepo/A/
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: it doesn't print any thing on the console. As soon as I remove the "-- myGitRepo/A/" it prints all the PR's.

Comment: What output do you get when you keep the path but remove the `--since`? Are you sure there have been any commits in the given time interval?

Comment: Surprisingly for me, it outputs the PR's(but these are not intended for the folder i specified...it brings all the PR's) when I remove the --since. Yes there have been commits in the given time interval.

Comment: What happens if you specify the date in the HHHH-MM-DD format after `--since`?

Comment: please check the above edited comment....The first filter where I am trying to extract PR titles raised for a specific folder is not working. It brings all the PR's. git --git-dir=.git log --merges -- myGitRepo/A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181870/discussion-between-b-t-anand-and-choroba).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue here is that git is trying to match the condition that `-- <path>` needs to be modified towards both parents. If you instruct git to check only towards one of the parents, I think the command could work.

Try the following (using `--first-parent`):

```
git --git-dir=.git log --first-parent --merges --since="Wed Oct 10 07:57:32 UTC 2018" -- myGitRepo/A/
```

Comment: yes... this resolved the issue since I was looking to extract PR merge titles destined on the master branch.

Comment: It does not include pull requests raised after rebase.